# grunt-contrib-jshint not show message

Tags: grunt-contrib-jshint

i have created a ne node project, i have installed a lot of modules and create the first index.js file

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "parser-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "parser test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "luca bottoni",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-cmd": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-exec": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

**index.js** (it's failed, because i want see jshint message!)

```
console.log("test");
a={a=6};
```

if i send the cmd jshint index.js from project folder i see (**work fine**):

```
index.js: line 3, col 5, Expected ':' and instead saw '='.
1 error
```

now i want use the grunt task to check my file

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
                     pkg:  grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
                     watch:{
                         scripts:{
                             files:["./*.js"],
                             tasks:['jshint']
                         }
                     },
                     jshint: {
                         files: ['Gruntfile.js',"index.js"]
                     }
                 });
// Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch:scripts']);
grunt.registerTask('jshint', ['jshint']);
};
```

now i try use single task jshint with command grunt jshint, but the don't see any message. if i use the watch, watch task only the first time and after not check any change on file index.js.

i can not understand why the direct command jshint work, but the task grunt stay freezed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved after many test

i have turn-on verbose information on grunt command

**grunt jshint --verbose** and i have see infinite:

Running "jshint" task

Running "jshint" task

Running "jshint" task

Running "jshint" task

Running "jshint" task

Running "jshint" task

The register task and task in definition have the same name "jshint" and i have modified the name in grunt.registerTask('**jshints**', ['jshint']);

now work fine